# Rails getting No route matches [PUT] "/manage_users"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails app with a page for a user to edit their own profile

`app/views/manage_users/edit.html.erb` and `app/views/manage_users/new.html.erb` contain:

```
<%= render 'form' %>
```

`app/views/manage_users/_formt.html.erb` contains:

```
<%= form_for(@user, :as => :user, :url => {:action => @form_action, :id => @user.id}) do |f| %>
```

When I fire up the page `http://localhost:3000/manage_users/2/edit` it shows me a typical form to edit a user object's data. If i blank out the email address http://snag.gy/atnmV.jpg and submit the form, I get an error that I would expect http://snag.gy/NRfwn.jpg and the url is now `http://localhost:3000/manage_users/2`:

```
Started PUT "/manage_users/2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-25 21:01:45 -0600
Processing by ManageUsersController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"B44/1b5m8usyAfe0hzLHNyjk/7Fpn5iEu3u6wGJMGL0=", "user"=>{"user_details_attributes"=>{"first_name"=>"Jeff", "last_name"=>"Smith", "id"=>"2"}, "email"=>"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "button"=>"", "id"=>"2"}
```

If i put the email address back in and submit the form, the url now points to `http://localhost:3000/manage_users?id=2` and I get the error `No route matches [PUT] "/manage_users"`

Why is it doing this and how can I fix it. If i just go to the initial page to edit a user and save it right away (instead of blanking out the email), everything works just fine.

app/controllers/manage_users_controller.rb

```
class ManageUsersController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :admin_only, :except => [:edit, :update]

  # GET /manage_users
  # GET /manage_users.json
  def index
    @users = User.active

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @users }
    end
  end

  # GET /manage_users/new
  # GET /manage_users/new.json
  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.build_user_details
    @form_action = 'create'

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end

  # GET /manage_users/1/edit
  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @permissions_disabled = params[:id].to_i == current_user.id.to_i
    #p @permissions_disabled
    able_to_edit_profile?

    session[:return_to] ||= request.referer

    @form_action = 'update'
  end

  # POST /manage_users
  # POST /manage_users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    #p "in create"
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { 
            flash[:notice] = 'User was successfully created.'
            redirect_to(:action => :index) 
        }
        format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new", notice: 'Error creating user.' }
        format.json { render json: @user, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
     end
  end

  # PUT /manage_users/1
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    able_to_edit_profile?

    # required for settings form to submit when password is left blank
    if params[:user][:password].blank?
      params[:user].delete("password")
      params[:user].delete("password_confirmation")
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        @user.save    

        # sign the user in with their new password so it doesn't redirect to the login screen
        if current_user == @user
          sign_in @user, :bypass => true
        end

        format.html { 
        p "in success format.html"
            flash[:notice] = 'User was successfully updated.'
            redirect_to session.delete(:return_to)
        }
      else
      p "in else"
        format.html { render action: "edit", notice: 'Error updating user.' }
        #format.html { 

            #flash[:notice] = @user.errors
        #   redirect_to edit_manage_user_path(@user)
        #}
      end
    end
  end

  private 

  # If the user is not an admin and trying to edit someone else's profile, redirect them
  def able_to_edit_profile?
    if !current_user.try(:admin?) && current_user.id != @user.id
        flash[:alert] = "That area is for administrators only."
        redirect_to :root
    end
  end
end
```

**EDIT**

So by changing this:

```
format.html { render action: "edit", notice: 'Error updating user.' }
```

to:

```
format.html {               
    flash[:notice] = @user.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
    redirect_to edit_manage_user_path(@user)
}
```

I'm able to circumvent the issue. I'm still curious as to why rendering 'edit' doesn't work after a failed update.

Comment: What does the form look like?

Comment: The form is irrelevant i believe since i've posted the `form_for` line. The question is already long so i don't want to post anything that's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

When you render the edit action from the update method (in the failure path), it doesn't run the edit method, so @form_action is nil when you render the form.  You'll need to address that.

I usually don't need to set the url, only in rare cases do I.  You may be able to leave that out and let rails take care of the url and HTTP method.

Comment: Just to explain this a little more in detail: When '@form_action' is nil, the url only consists of the id param, meaning its "/manage_users?id=x". Since there is a @user (not a User.new instance in which case it would figure you want to create a user), rails is guessing you want to update '@user' hence the method is PUT. If you redirect_to instead of render to edit, it should work alright.

Comment: @Chai The problem with redirecting is that how can I set the object errors in a flash variable? Also, I guess i still don't understand why redirect_to would work, but render 'edit' won't. Can you please elaborate more? I guess I don't understand why if you hit the url `localhost:3000/manage_users/2/edit`, it works just fine, but if you render 'edit' from a failed update, that doesn't work.

Comment: You may be confusing the `render edit` (rendering a view) with `edit` (calling a method).  Usually, the update method will render edit on a error, not redirect. ie - you will stay on the 'show' url (/manage_users/2).  If you have instance variables that you want to access in the edit view, you need to instantiate them.  You can do this in the update method.